# Ok... I've been sock puppeting

Tags: support, status-completed, sock-puppets

Was having some laugh comparing my profile with my colleagues, were 20 points apart.

So I created another account, etc etc.

Then, I was told by this other guy that can lead to banning.

But I can't "right my wrong" and unvote? :/ I get a "you voted in the past 18min. It's now locked" etc.

Edit- just for disclosure purpose, it's [user1621578](https://stackoverflow.com/u/1621578) (but it can't get more obvious).

Comment: That's a lot of votes. They'll get auto-reversed at midnight UTC. But it's good that you've admitted you did something wrong; it's a good learning process. A moderator can also merge your accounts to instantly invalidate all the votes between the two accounts (which they'll probably do when they see this).

Comment: Wow, OK, those comments were really going over the top. I'm just going to say it here: **people have got to STOP obsessing over false voting cases.** Just because somebody has had a serial vote reversal in their rep history **does not automatically mean they have a sock puppet or the serial voting was their own doing and they need to be punished for it**. If you think something suspicious is going on with a user, feel free to flag them and we'll look at every flag, but not every flag results in an automatic warning or suspension. These cases are not anybody's business but ours.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn You should have spared that movie-watching image. That was soooo coool :D

Comment: Oh, that. Here it is again: http://i40.tinypic.com/111ji8o.gif

Comment: I'm going to second what BoltClock said, there are _many_ things on the site equally or more deserving of attention than voting patterns. We can't get so caught up in trying to prevent people from gaming the system that we lose focus on making the system better as a whole, and teaching people how it works.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I've verified your sock puppet and merged it into your main account, so the fraudulent votes have been removed and you'll get to keep the posts that were made under your sock puppet account.

Yes, the other guy is right: sock puppeting is a bannable offense. But for your honesty and initiative in coming to meta to post, I'll withhold a suspension. All we ask is that you take care not to do this again. Thanks for your contributions to the site!

Comment: Posts like this are proof that SO rocks, and cares about community.  Thank you for thinking the issue out and handling it in a way that reinforces the desire to "build something" at SO.